Representability of stack of finite maps between curves
I am interested in the following moduli problem: The moduli functor $\mathcal{F}$ has $T$-points:

a nodal $n$-pointed curve $C/T$ of genus $g$.
a nodal $b$-pointed curve $D/T$ of genus $h$.
a finite surjective map $f: C \to D$ over $T$ s.t. over each geometric point $s \to T$ the automorphism group of $f$ is finite in the sense that there are only finitely many pairs of automorphims $(\varphi: C_s \to C_s, \psi: D_s \to D_s)$ s.t. $f_s \circ \varphi = \psi \circ f_s$.

I strongly believe that this problem is representable by a proper Deligne-Mumford stack, but cannot prove the result.
My main obstacle is that I cannot embed this functor into some well known Moduli problem such as a HOM-stack or Hilbert stack because the target curve $D$ is not necessary stable. My other idea was to consider a stack of stable maps $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}(\mathcal{C}_{h,b})$ of stable maps that parametrizes possibly non-finte maps to stable target curves $D$ and then adding copies of the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $D$, to make this map finite. But there is no canonical way to to that as this depends on the choice of a morphism from the components that are contracted to $\mathbb{P}^1$.
Is there another access point to proving representability of that functor by a stack with good properties?

First prove it is an Artin stack (automatic in this case); and then prove the diagonal is finite (so that it is even a Deligne-Mumford stack).

Could you elaborate a bit on why in my case it is automatic that this is an Artin stack? I see that every descent datum is effective, but how can I conclude the existence of a smooth atlas?

This follows from "folk results."  One place where the details are written is Propositions 2.3 and 2.6 of the following:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.5224
